# The error is addr and port conflict with endpoint

Tags: tezos-client, rpc

I run to tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 and my tezos-client is connect 127.0.0.1:8732 , so i input in tezos-client to tezos-client --addr 127.0.0.1 --port 8732 -l transfer 100 from bootstrap1 to bootstrap2 for watch wallet format but erroris run this photo.[image]

How can i do fix error. THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a config file for `tezos-client`. It is located at `~/.tezos-client/config.json`  In this config, you have a setting for `endpoint`, which is the correct parameter (`--addr` and `--port` are deprecated and will be removed soon).

You are telling client one thing, but it is reading something else from config. You should stop using the --addr/--port and use --endpoint.

Comment: THX for your help!!!!!!!!!!!